# If E.T was left on Earth by his spaceship, and he couldn't fly up to it, how come he could fly in that bike?

Tags: plot-explanation, et-the-extra-terrestrial

In the movie **ET**(1982), at the near beginning of the film *ET* is left behind by his spaceship. He simply couldn't fly up to get back to it and he stayed on Earth as seen below:

[image]

We see in a later scene that the boy is riding a bike with ET in the front basket as shown below:
[image]

**How is it that ET couldn't fly to get to his ship at the start of the movie and here he suddenly can fly on a bike?**

Comment: According to the [TV Trope page for E.T](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/ETTheExtraterrestrial), *'the novelization claims his growing telekinetic powers are a side-effect of the same process that is killing him.'* - I can't find the relevant quote just yet though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it's a different thing to fly a spaceship back to a planet and fly a bike a few meters into the air. Just like you can throw a stone a few meters up in the air but not to Alpha Centauri, E.T.'s powers have limits.

Comment: This is not answering the original question. He’s flying himself back to the ship, not the ship into space.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's because E.T is a teenager and doesn't know all of its powers. Think of it like Clark Kent in Smallville, as Clark aged, he started to discover his new powers and had to practice controlling them. He just didn't become Superman over night it took years to fine tune his powers and become the Superman.

Comment: Do you have any source to back your answer up?

Comment: The book states he's 10 million years old. I thought it also said something about it being young for his species but I can't find anything to back that up.